# viewWillTransitionToSize causes non-rotating view controller to resize and reposition

Tags: ios, rotation, viewwilltransitiontosize, swift2

A lot of people have discussed techniques for mimicking the native iOS camera app (where the UI elements pivot in-place as the device rotates). I actually asked a question about it before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027948/need-help-setting-up-an-interface-where-rotation-is-fixed-for-most-elements-but/33045519#33045519). Most people have you lock the orientation of the UI, but then force a transformation on just the elements that you want to pivot. This works, but the elements don't pivot with the smooth animations you see in the native iOS app and it leads some issues. Specifically, part of my interface allows users to share without leaving this interface, but when the sharing view gets rotated, it comes out off-center. So I wanted to find a different way to do this.

I found a link to [Apple's AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/) sample, which got me off to a start here. I'm new to this stuff, but I managed to convert it from Obj-C to Swift already. Below is the key element of what I'm currently using:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

        //Code here performs animations during the rotation

        let deltaTransform: CGAffineTransform = coordinator.targetTransform()
        let deltaAngle: CGFloat = atan2(deltaTransform.b, deltaTransform.a)
        var currentRotation: CGFloat = self.nonRotatingView.layer.valueForKeyPath("transform.rotation.z") as! CGFloat

        // Adding a small value to the rotation angle forces the animation to occur in a the desired direction, preventing an issue where the view would appear to rotate 2PI radians during a rotation from LandscapeRight -> LandscapeLeft.
        currentRotation += -1 * deltaAngle + 0.0001;
        self.nonRotatingView.layer.setValue(currentRotation, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.z")

        }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
            print("rotation completed");
            // Code here will execute after the rotation has finished
            // Integralize the transform to undo the extra 0.0001 added to the rotation angle.
            var currentTransform: CGAffineTransform = self.nonRotatingView.transform
            currentTransform.a = round(currentTransform.a)
            currentTransform.b = round(currentTransform.b)
            currentTransform.c = round(currentTransform.c)
            currentTransform.d = round(currentTransform.d)
            self.nonRotatingView.transform = currentTransform
    })

    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
}
```

I then have separate view controllers for icons that do the same transformation in the opposite direction. The icons actually pivot in place properly now (with smooth animations and everything) and the camera preview stays properly oriented.

The problem is, the non-rotating view gets resized and everything gets misplaced when I rotate the device from portrait to landscape or vice-versa. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working (though it took me way more time than it should have). I needed to set the width and height parameters of the non-rotating view to remove at build time and then added the following to viewDidLoad():

```
let nonRotatingWidth = nonRotatingView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)
let nonRotatingHeight = nonRotatingView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
nonRotatingView.addConstraints([nonRotatingWidth, nonRotatingHeight])
```

This uses the new Swift 2 constraint syntax, which is relatively concise and easy to read.

I've also tinkered with only using the new constraint syntax (and no transformations) to achieve the same type of interface via updateViewConstraints() (see [my question about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223558/)). I believe that approach is a cleaner way to create this type of interface, but I have not yet been able to make it work without crashing at runtime.

Comment: Hello! Can you, please-please-please, share the code of the view controller that you created? I'm trying to make exactly the same thing as you described and you approach is looking as THE solution! I tried to use the code that you provided but I can't put it all together working.. I believe I can go the same way as you but I'm sure it will take much more time. I would really appreciate if you could share the code!

Comment: After series of experiments I finally did it! With hints that you provided. Also I think it is worth mentioning that we should add this to view controller so that the non rotating view does not move sideways:

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        nonRotatingView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds))
    }

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply -- glad you got it working though.